Expressing powers of Dirichlet series coefficients in terms of the coefficients
Assume we have a Dirichlet series which have a Euler product, typically in the case of $GL(2)$ objects it would look like
$$
L(s) = \sum_{n \geq 1} \lambda(n) n^{-s} = \prod_p (1-\alpha_p p^{-s})^{-1}(1-\beta_p p^{-s})^{-1}
$$
where the sums are over positive integers $n$ and primes $p$.
Is there a way to express $\lambda(p)^n$ in terms of the $\lambda(p^k)$ in a pretty explicit way? In practice, I understood that it can be done and found explicitly by expanding and identifying coefficients, since $\lambda(p) = \alpha + \beta$ (I drop the $p$-indices from now on) so that
$$
\lambda(p)^n = (\alpha + \beta)^n = \sum_k \binom{n}{k} \alpha^k \beta^{n-k}
$$
but we also get, by expanding the Euler product and identifying:
$$
\lambda(p^k) = \sum_{i = 0}^k \alpha^i \beta^{k-i}.
$$
We can therefore recursively find an explicit expression for a given $n$, but is there a nice closed formula in general?

Is the latter sum over $i \in\mathbb Z$?

@Nolord $i$ is between $0$ and $k$, but matching the coefficient corresponding to $n = p^{k}$ is the Dirichlet series and in the Euler product

This is just the Hecke relations:
$$\lambda(mn) = \sum_{d \mid (m,n)} \mu(d) \lambda\left(\frac{m}{d}\right) \lambda\left(\frac{n}{d}\right)$$
and
$$\lambda(m) \lambda(n) = \sum_{d \mid (m,n)} \lambda\left(\frac{mn}{d^2}\right).$$
